# Why does my cloth simulation fall even though it shouldn't?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I followed the instructions in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vVoQ-1U0SY) exactly, but still I get this result.

Here are my ncolth settings
[image: Nclot[![h settings][2]][2]]

The collision settings are set as default.

Here is the result which is unsatisfactory.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How can i share the file?

Comment: You can share it here [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com), check if my answer helps first though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Increase Physics Properties > Collision > Softbody And Cloth > **Friction** value for bed (mattress) object.

[image]

Comment: While friction would slow or stop the cloth from falling, i wonder if it's not a case of empty pin group.

Comment: I tried simple cube with a plane on top of that, with just a decent move on side (over an edge) and it felt down with default setup quickly (even faster with dense topo).

Comment: I changed the friction to max and it worked. It stopped falling. Thanks